# MS Access 2013 Form: Force field input to begin at the start

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I have to do intake for new employees, which requires filling out a form.  Normally I'd be able to watch over and clean data as they go, but we often have to intake multiple employees at a time, which is why I need to make the form foolproof.

Is there a way to force the input to go to the beginning of a field instead of being able to click in the middle of it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sVwN.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use in the OnFocus event of the control:

```
Me!YourControlName.SelStart = 0
```

Comment: This seems to only work with On Click, the Got focus event doesn't seem to work.  Probably due to the Input Mask?

Comment: Maybe. How about the OnEnter event?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work their either.  I would just assume that it has to do with the order of events.

Comment: Hmmm.  This works, but is it possible to disable it after 1 instance?  So basically if they screw up, they can click anywhere?

Comment: Yes, if you can create a rule for when entering is to edit the content or to edit the content ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to make the cursor go to the first input field or to any particular field. If this is what you need, try putting docmd.gotocontrol "controlName" on the onOpen event of the form. More about the docmd.gotocontrol.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192079.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I'm trying to force the input at the beginning of the field instead of being able to click in the middle of the field.

I have an input mask in a cellphone field, but people can click in the middle of the text, which makes it less than foolproof.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/0sVwN.png

Basically they can click on a middle digit instead of being forced to start at the beginning of the text.